# Main page on safari 10.5.8 apple

Tags: mac, safari

i don't know how to change the main page. I don't know what it is called but it is the one where you open safari and the first page comes up. how can i change what the website it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Safari → Preferences → General and set the homepage to your desired page.